# Change style of Joined line in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: charts, style

How do I change the style of *just* the joining line (e.g., to Red) in a chart such as this?

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{23, 45, 27}, 
{54, 12, 86, 72}, 
{45, 22, 18, 66}},
 Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In version 12.2.0, you can post-process to re-style the *joined* line using the replacement rule  `{g_GraphicsGroup :> g, l_Line :> {Thick, Red, l}}` (the first rule prevents fences and whiskers from being re-styled):

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{23, 45, 27}, {54, 12, 86, 72}, {45, 22, 18, 66}}, 
    Joined -> True] /. {g_GraphicsGroup :> g, l_Line :> {Thick, Red, l}}
```

[image]

In version 11.3.0, simpler rule, `l_Line :> {Red, Thick, l}`, is sufficient:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{23, 45, 27}, {54, 12, 86, 72}, {45, 22, 18, 66}}, 
  Joined -> True] /. l_Line :> {Red, Thick, l}
```

[image]

Comment: Ugh... so no "JoinStyle" or other equivalent option?  Oh well.  But thanks!  But problems in v. 12.0?

Comment: @David & Anton, it turns out fences and whiskers (and polygons) are all inside a `GraphicsGroup` and the join line is rendered separately. So a simple modification of the replacement rule works in version 12.2.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very ad hoc approach (I assume better solutions exists):

```
data = {{23, 45, 27}, {54, 12, 86, 72}, {45, 22, 18, 66}};
gr1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> False];
gr2 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> True];

linePart = Complement[gr2[[1]], gr1[[1]]];
pos = Position[gr2, linePart[[1]], Infinity];

ReplacePart[gr2, pos[[1]] -> linePart /. RGBColor[___] :> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1)... but as you say, rather ad hoc.

Answer (score 4):

```
 data = {{23, 45, 27}, {54, 12, 86, 72}, {45, 22, 18, 66}}, ;
```

It turns out the color of the joined line is the color for the first box wrapped with `Darker`.

For the case with single collection of datasets as in OP:

**i.** If a `ChartStyle` is specified, say `ChartStyle  -> "Rainbow"`, we replace `Darker[ColorData["Rainbow"]@0]` with the desired color:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> True, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"] /. 
 Darker[ColorData["Rainbow"]@0] -> Directive[Red, Thick]
```

[image]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> True, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"] /. 
 Darker[ColorData["Pastel"]@0] -> Directive[Red, Thick]
```

[image]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> True, ChartStyle -> {Cyan, Purple, Magenta}] /. 
  Darker[Cyan] -> Directive[Red, Thick]
```

[image]

**ii.** For the case with default chart style, we can use `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme `` to discover the default chart style:

```
"ChartDefaultStyle" /. 
   (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, BoxWhiskerChart])
```

> ```
>  Blend[Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2], #1] &
> ```

The list of colors is:

```
Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient
```

[image]

So we do:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, Joined -> True] /. 
 Darker[Lighter[First @ System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2]] -> 
  Directive[Red, Thick]
```

[image]